Opamp voltage doubler clipping well below positive rail
I have a TL072 hooked up as a simple voltage doubler:

A resistor in negative feedback
Same value resistor from inverting input to GND.
Opamp is powered by +/- 15V

This works as expected (Vout = 2x Vin), BUT clips at around +9V. Regardless of load, regardless of R values.
Negative it goes down to -13.5V as expected.
Have tried several TL072, same results.
What am I missing?


Schematic, please with all values of resistors, load included.

Done! (sorry, first post...)

Are you sure nothing is loading the output more? Maybe next stage? Based on the datasheet if tou load output to cca 27mA the max output voltage will be 10V, just for orentation..

Yes, I've rebuilt this part of the circuit on a breadboard, exactly as shown. Input is DC from a voltage divider (10k pot).

@BramMylemans no worries ... Have you added the 2 decoupling capacitors (0.1uF min)?

If possible, please measure the positive rail close to the opamp pin with the second channel of the oscilloscope when clipping happens.

Added the decoupling caps, no change. The opamp power pins show clean +-15V, no ripple or anything while clipping.
I tried the opamp as a voltage follower and it also clips at 6V below the positive rail.
I think I have a bad batch of TL072 (yes, from that famous Chinese webshop... but with TI logo and all).
Thanks all for your help!

Well, it seems you got a "typical batch"... Mystery solved. ;-)

Are you sure you have the correct pinout? Pin 8 +15V?

@Spehro 'speff' Pefhany 100% sure. I've done some additional testing and the opamps are just bad - the output will clip at Vcc-6V in any configuration.

@BramMylemans Weird. I wonder what they actually are.
